# Develop web project using ASP.NET MVC ver 1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone have an experience with developing a big web app using ASP.NET MVC ver 1?

If yes:

- What troubles can be expected?
- What are the biggest risks?
- What are the main points the attention should be paid for?
- Is there any alternative for ASP.NET MVC right now? And how reasonable this can be?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not directly related but this SO post may help you:<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264305/are-there-any-projects-with-source-code-to-download-developed-in-mvc-framework/1264321#1264321

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In brief, just my opinions ...

**Risks & Troubles (I found) :**

- Routes can be a bit of a sticking point, IMHO until you get a complete handle on them, they're just a little awkward!
- Mocking of the Http objects is not as easy as I'd hoped, because of dependencies
- I'd guess the biggest risk is developing an applicaiton before the dev tem is completely up to speed with all the MVC features etc.

**Main points to pay attention to**

- Make sure that your domain design is correct from the outset.
- Choose a good mocking framework for your unit tests
- Take a look at The microsoft blog engine code: Oxite (downloadable from codeplex) excellent place to see how things should be done
- Get a good book! I've looked at a couple but found this one the best : 
  http://www.apress.com/book/view/1430210079

There are other MVC frameworks. Wikipedia has a list:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller

As a UI developer my preference would be to use MVC over Webforms now.

Comment: About risks & troubles => I disagree about routes and mocking Http objects but 3rd point is perfect. Upvoted... :)

Answer (score 0):

[Carsonified](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55029/ryan-carson) is staging a public wireframing of his new "hello" app written in ASP.Net MVC. It's worth keeping an eye on.

http://carsonified.com/blog/carsonified/sketches-wireframes-logo-ideas-meet-our-new-app/